# How to calculate the energy of a particle in superposition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, particle-physics, superposition

lets say we have particle bc particle bc has a 50/50 odds of either turning into particle b or c
each has energy of 2 units. particle A takes the energy from either b or c depending on the result assuming that particle A is in superposition what is the energy of particle A

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're thinking about it the wrong way around. A system is at superposition, for instance:
$$
\vert\psi\rangle  = \alpha\vert1\rangle  +\beta\vert0\rangle
$$
where for $\vert1\rangle$ and $\vert0\rangle$ we have $E_1$ and $E_0$ respectively. The energy of the system is not obvious until we make a measurement, then the system would collapse (if the basis of the measurement is $\vert1\rangle$ and $ \vert0\rangle$) to either of the the states with either of the energies. But if you have an ensemble (a large amount of coppies)of your system then you can find what is called expectation value which is denoted  $\langle E\rangle$ and is defined by:

$$
\langle E\rangle = \langle\psi\vert\hat H\vert\psi\rangle
$$

Which would give the result:

$$
\langle E\rangle = \alpha^2 E_1 + \beta^2 E_0
$$

Note that $\alpha^2 +\beta^2 =1$ because of normalization. This seems like a average of energy if you want to call it.
\

Tell me if I understood what you asked.

Comment: danm you guys are geniuses you make me seem like a kindergardner with my knowledge